# TikZ nodes: how to pretend that all characters have ascenders and descenders?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a few boxes with TikZ, each of them containing one or more words, sometimes with multiple lines. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{
align=center,
every node/.style=draw,
node distance=1em,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, every node/.append style=on chain]
\node {a};
\node {b};
\node {g};
\node {a\\a};
\node {g\\b};
\node {b\\g};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: before]

However, I'd like all one-line boxes to have the same height and all two-line boxes as well, regardless what characters are used.

As a work-around, I can do something like this:

```
\node {a\strut};
\node {b\strut};
\node {g\strut};
\node {a\strut\\a\strut};
\node {g\strut\\b\strut};
\node {b\strut\\g\strut};
```

[image: after]

This yields the expected result, but it is quite cumbersome to type if there are many nodes.

Is there some way to get this more automatically?

I've tried using `execute at end node=\strut`, which works for the one-line nodes and for the bottom of the two-line nodes. I've also tried `execute at begin node=\strut`, but this didn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on Zarko's answer, the following trick
redefines `\\` to mean what `\nl` means in Zarko's answer.
Hence you can use `\\` as usual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \def\tikz@align@newline{\vphantom{bg}\pgfutil@protect\tikz@align@newline@}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=0,start chain,
        every node/.style={
            on chain,draw,align=center,
            execute at end node=\vphantom{bg}
        }
    ]
        \node(a){a};
        \node(b){b};
        \node(g){g};
        \node(aa){a\\a};
        \node(ag){a\\g};
        \node(ba){b\\a};
        \node(bg){b\\g};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer (+1). Does your definition not need to be closed by  `\makeatother`?

Comment: Ahhhh, I tend to forget to close it because I need to hack into internals too many times. I know this is against the *community convention*, so listen LaTeX beginners, do this at your own risk.

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1cm,
    start chain, 
    execute at end node={\vphantom{bg}},  % <---
    every node/.append style={on chain, draw, align=center},               
                    ]
\def\nl{\vphantom{bg}\\} % <---
\node {a};
\node {b};
\node {y};
\node {a\nl a};
\node {g\nl b};
\node {b\nl g};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\\ ` is let to be `\tikz@align@newline` inside a node. So `\def\tikz@align@newline{\vphantom{bg}\pgfutil@protect\tikz@align@newline@}` allows you to use `\\ ` as usual. Another possibility is `font=\vphantom{bg}`, but it did only insert the strut at the last line (which I cannot tell why).

Comment: @Symbol1, indeed! Your suggestion is astonishing! I'm not  familiar with LaTeX internals. Do you like to wrote an answer about this? O r can I wrote addendum with your proposition?